# Where git-p4 save information about perforce depot

Tags: git, perforce, git-p4

I'm performing migration from perforce to git using git p4. I need to keep sync my git repo with perforce server. I just need to know where does git-p4 store information about perforce depot after git p4 clone and later that use for git p4 sync.

Answer (score 2):

For the basic setup, `git p4` uses the standard [client configuration](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-p4#_client_spec) of the [P4 tool chain](https://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4guide/Content/P4Guide/chapter.configuration.html). You can overwrite that using [P4 Git configuration options](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-p4#_configuration_variables) if you need.

When using `git p4 sync` git relies on P4 depo syntax + the client configuration to figure out where to pull the changes from.

If you're wondering where the actual revisions created from the P4 CLs, they are all put into [`refs/remotes/p4/master`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-p4#_sync)

Comment: I've checked the source code of git-p4 and found that It is parsing depot information from the commit log. Actually, git-p4 add depot information along with an original message in the commit log.